# confused how to use jquery getJSON properly

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to use a jquery getJSON get information for my table from a php file, and its not working. Can someone give me a few pointers as to where I am going wrong:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("input#autofill").click(function()
{
$.get("last_year_ISBN.php",
    function(data){
    var isbns = $.parseJSON(data);  //creates a javascript object.
                  $.each(isbns, function(){
                    var elements = document.getElementById("booklist").getElementsByTagName("input");
                    for (var i=0, i<elements.length; i++)
                    {
                        elements[i] = this;
                    }
                    });
                  },
                  "json");

    });
});
```

HTML/php

```
<?php
            $file = fopen("SGS_Fall_Booklist.csv", "r");
            $entry= fgetcsv($file);
            echo $entry[0] . $_GET["program"] . $entry[1] . $GET["school"] . $entry[2] . $GET["term"] . "<br>";
            //COMMENTED OUT FOR TESTINGecho "<input type='submit' name='checkall' value='AutoFill (last years ISBN's)'></input><br>";
            //if ($entry[0] == $_GET["program"] && $entry[1] ==$GET["school"] && $entry[2] == $GET["term"])
            //{                                 
            echo "<table id='booklist'><tr>
                             <th>Edit</th>
                             <th class='coursename'>" . $entry[6] . "</th>
                             <th class='startdate'>" . $entry[7] . "</th>
                             <th class='booktitle'>" . $entry[17]. "</th>
                             <th class='author'>" . $entry[18]. "</th>
                             <th class='isbn'>" . $entry[16]. "</th>
                         </tr>";
            while(! feof($file))
            {
                $entry = fgetcsv($file); 

                echo    "<tr>
                            <td><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                            <td class='coursename'>" . $entry[6] . "</td>
                            <td class='startdate'>" . $entry[7] . "</td>
                            <td class='booktitle'>" . $entry[17]. "</td>
                            <td class='author'>" . $entry[18]. "</td>
                            <td class='isbn'><input class='ISBN_number' type='text' value='";               

                if(isset($_GET["checkall"]))
                {
                    echo $entry[16];
                }
                echo        "'size='13' maxlength='13'></input></td>    
                      </tr>";                   
            }

            //}
            echo "</table>";
            fclose($file);
```

?>

external php file

```
<?php
$file = fopen("SGS_Fall_Booklist.csv", "r");
$entry = fgetcsv($file);    //discard the first title line
$i=0;
while(! feof($file))
{
    $entry = fgetcsv($file); 

    $isbns=[$i] = $entry;
    $i++;
}
fclose($file);
echo json_encode($isbns);
?>
```

---

I have changed my code as hyperslug suggested and it still doesn't work. The alert(data) does return the whole json statement. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input#autofill").click(function()
    {
        $.get("last_year_ISBN.php",
                  function(data){
                  alert(data);
                  var isbns = $.parseJSON(data);    //creates a javascript object.
                  var elements = $('#booklist .ISBN_number');
                  $.each(isbns, function(index, obj){
                    //var elements = document.getElementById("booklist").getElementsByTagName("input");
                    //for (var i=0, i<elements.length; i++)
                    //{
                        //elements[i].value = this;
                    //}
                    $(elements[index]).val(obj);
                    });
                  },
                  "json");



    });
});
```

---

I finally figured out my problem! I was using json_encode on the php side which sends the request back as json. The .get call was reading it in AS JSON (note the last parameter) and automatically turning it into a javascript object. Therefore, of course my parseJSON line wouldn't work, I was parsing a javascript object, not json text!!

Comment: Could you explain more clearly, what you are trying to achieve with your javascript.

Comment: Here's where you have to learn how to use the Chrome/Firefox debugger.  Instead of `alert` use `console.log`.  After `var elements = $('#booklist .ISBN_number');` put lines like `console.log(elements)` and `console.log(isbns)`. This will output the values to the console, `CTRL-SHIFT-J` in Chrome, `CTRL-F12` in Firefox/Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery `.each` loop gives you an index and a reference to each object in `isbns`.  If `isbns` is a simple array and has exactly the same number of elements as your `booklist` has rows,

```
var elements = $('#booklist .ISBN_number');
$.each(isbns, function(index, obj){
    $(elements[index]).val(obj);
});
```

should fill your ISBN `<input>` fields.

If `isbns` is actually an array of objects, you'll have to reference that value by name:

```
    $(elements[index]).val(obj.ISBN);
```

Comment: +1. Nice. I even updated the end of my answer to refer to yours, since I'd talked about the problem without giving a specific answer. But note that this assumes that the number of ISBNs returned in the JSON is less than or equal to the number of inputs, so it wouldn't hurt to add an if test to break out of the `$.each` if `index` reaches `elements.length`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, True. I'm more likely to construct the table dynamically or only fill in ISBN's on matching row Id's (if he had an Id).  I could probably recommend a better approach if I was more familiar with PHP.

Comment: Hyperslug, thanks very much for the comments. I understand much better how to use the each function now. Your code makes sense but for some reason it still doesn't work. As nnnnnn sugested below, I put in an alert statement and it did return the json statement. Do you know what might still be the issue? I am reposting the changed code below.

Comment: @hyperslug What does $('#booklist .ISBN_number'); mean? Specifically the `#booklist .ISBN_number` part. Is .ISBN_number some sort of class?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the only problem, but I can see two problems with the following code, as per the comments I've added within the code and the explanation below:

```
$.get("last_year_ISBN.php",
   function(data){

      alert(data); // <--- NEW DEBUGGING ALERT HERE

      var isbns = $.parseJSON(data);  //creates a javascript object.
      $.each(isbns, function(){
         var elements = document.getElementById("booklist").getElementsByTagName("input");
         // PROBLEM: you're setting all input elements to the current item
         //          from the $.each
         for (var i=0, i<elements.length; i++)
         {
            elements[i] = this; // <--- SHOULD BE elements[i].value = this
         }
      });
   },
   "json"
);
```

1. I assume your intention is to update the HTML inputs to display the data from your JSON. To do that you need to say `elements[i].value = this`, or, with jQuery, `$(elements[i]).val(this)`.
2. Your `$.each` loop iterates over all the items from your JSON, but for each item you then  run the same `for` loop and update *all* inputs within "booklist" to the current item.

I'd suggest that first you put a debugging `console.log(data)` or `alert(data)` statement in to confirm that your callback is actually getting called, and what data it is receiving. (I've added that above.)

Then to fix problem (2) you need to assign the individual inputs to the appropriate values from your JSON but I can't really suggest how to do that without seeing the structure of the JSON.

EDIT: Just saw hyperslug's answer - that is what I was talking about with problem (2). Assuming your JSON is a simple array with elements that correspond one-to-one to your inputs that should work perfectly. If your JSON is more complicated please update your question to show its format.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `$("input#autofill")` is probably returns nothing.
There is no input with ID attribute 'autofill'

Comment: Oops, sorry, I do have that, I just didn't copy that into my snippet. THis is the code <input type="button" id="autofill" value="autofill"></input>

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:

```
$isbns=[$i] = $entry;
```

should be:

```
$isbns[$i] = $entry;
```

Comment: If you open the json from your browser, does it display correctly?

Comment: When you open the php, that should return the isbn numbers, does that look ok or is it truncated?

Comment: open http://www.mysite.com/externalfile.php does this return an error or does it display correctly as per @topek

Comment: I just checked the php and yes, it does display the json code

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP could use a little improvement:

```
$isbns = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($file)) {
   $isbns[] = $line;
}

echo json_encode($isbns);
```

However, why are you using an AJAX call to fill in an html form, using the same source data as the PHP script which generated the form in the first place?

Comment: At the moment, I am just practicing with the code... But the real reason why I am using the same source data is because I want to display ISBN info from the source data ONLY if the user wants it. This is because its really last years data...